# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver though jar was added

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting the below error though i have added jar to my classpath.

error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at com.Class.Class19.getConnection(Class19.java:19)
 at com.Class.Class19.main(Class19.java:11)
```

i have tried by adding both sqlserverjdbc.jar and sqlserverjdbc4.jar to the classpath

Comment: Are you running via an IDE? CLI? If CLI, what's your command look like?

Comment: You need to add code or the command. In addition, dump tour Classpath.